# Locate points inside a Isoband/Isochrone

Tags: r, ggplot2, geolocation, interpolation, r-sf

Part of my master's thesis involve doing some kriging spatial interpolation. I'm mapping the spread of agriculture into Europe from the Near east using an ordinary kriging interpolation over a map of Europe. I then rendered the map on ggplot. With the following code :

```
map_500 <- ggplot()+
geom_contour_filled(data = tapas_kriging_sf, aes(x = x, y = y, z=var1.pred), binwidth = 500)+ 
geom_sf(data = world, fill = "transparent", color = "grey")+ 
geom_sf(data = water, fill = "white")+ geom_sf(data = TAPAS_sf, size = 0.05)+ geom_sf(data = XYZ_sf, size = 0.05, color = "red")+ 
coord_sf(xlim = c(XYZ_bbox$xmax+1,XYZ_bbox$xmin-1), ylim = c(XYZ_bbox$ymax+1, XYZ_bbox$ymin-1), expand = FALSE)+ 
labs(title = "Isochrones Map of Europe and the Near East (TAPAS)", fill = "Isochrones") 
map_500
```

This produces the following image :

[image]

EDIT : Here's more information about the nature of the tapas_kriging_sf. It's an sf object, where each row is a point of the map with a value corresponding to the interpolation value (var1.pred) of that part of the map.

```
   var1.pred var1.var            geometry     x     y
1   6725.361       NA POINT (-10.5 34.79) -10.5 34.79
2   6730.202       NA POINT (-10.4 34.79) -10.4 34.79
3   6734.932       NA POINT (-10.3 34.79) -10.3 34.79
4   6739.531       NA POINT (-10.2 34.79) -10.2 34.79
5   6743.977       NA POINT (-10.1 34.79) -10.1 34.79
6   6748.251       NA POINT (-10   34.79) -10.0 34.79
7   6752.330       NA POINT (-9.9  34.79)  -9.9 34.79
8   6756.193       NA POINT (-9.8  34.79)  -9.8 34.79
9   6759.822       NA POINT (-9.7  34.79)  -9.7 34.79
10  6763.195       NA POINT (-9.6  34.79)  -9.6 34.79
```

Now as you can see, the entirety of Europe is structured in colored "ribbons" called Isochrones or Isobands representing the arrival of agriculture at a give date (For example, in the yellow Isochrone, agriculture arrives at the earliest at the date of 8500 calBP...)

Scattered on this map, you can observe several red points. These points were not used to build the interpolation and come from another dataset.

**My objective is : I'd like to create a column in this latter dataset which references each red points with the Isochrone it is located in.**

For examples, for the red point in the Baleares (where you can see the arrow pointing), I'd like to have in the same row but in another column named "Isochrones" that it belongs to the Isochrone (7000,7500].

I figured out that my best bet would probably to polygonize the different isochrones and use st_intersect() or st_contains() to check for each point where they are located, but I have trouble creating a polygon of the Isochrones from the ggplot() map.

To better understand what I did, here's the entirety of the kriging process done with another data and semi-random point, as with ggplot.

Thanks in advance :)

I used ggplot_build() to get the layer from the map containing the filled contour (Isochrone). I then try to convert it into an sf object and "polygonize" the different Isochrone but this led me nowhere.

EDIT :
I've reproduced a version of my code from start to finish with open data. The output is less perfect since my interpolation grid doesn't align specifically with my are of interest (Germany), in the original data I hide that by colouring the oceans in white to override the filled contour.
Here it is :

```
library(gstat)
library(sf)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)

##Data
no2 <- read_csv(system.file("external/no2.csv", 
                            package = "gstat"), show_col_types = FALSE)
no2_sf <- st_as_sf(no2, crs = "OGC:CRS84", coords = c("station_longitude_deg", "station_latitude_deg")) 
no2_sf <- st_transform(no2_sf, 32632)


##Kriging
#Interpolation raster
no2_bbox <- st_bbox(no2_sf)
cell_size <- 10000
x <- seq(no2_bbox$xmin, no2_bbox$xmax, by=cell_size)
y <- seq(no2_bbox$ymin, no2_bbox$ymax, by=cell_size)
no2_grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
no2_grid$tmp <- 1
plot(no2_grid$x, no2_grid$y, pch=19, cex=0.1)
no2_grid <- st_as_sf(no2_grid, coords = c("x","y"), crs = st_crs(no2_sf))
st_crs(no2_grid) <- st_crs(no2_sf)

#Variogram
no2_sample_variogram <- gstat::variogram(NO2~1, no2_sf)
plot(no2_sample_variogram, plot.numbers = TRUE)
no2_model_variogram <- vgm(psill = 16, "Exp", range = 200000, nugget = 1)
plot(no2_sample_variogram, no2_model_variogram)
no2_fit_variogram <- fit.variogram(no2_sample_variogram, no2_model_variogram)
plot(no2_sample_variogram, no2_fit_variogram)

#Ordinary Kriging
no2_sf <- no2_sf[!duplicated(no2_sf$geometry),] #check which observation were removed
no2_kriging <- gstat::krige(NO2~1, no2_sf, no2_grid, no2_fit_variogram)

no2_kriging$x <- st_coordinates(no2_kriging)[,1]
no2_kriging$y <- st_coordinates(no2_kriging)[,2]

##Ggplot
points <- data.frame(x = runif(10, min = no2_bbox$xmin, max = no2_bbox$xmax), y = runif(10, min = no2_bbox$ymin, max = no2_bbox$ymax))
points <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("x","y"), crs = st_crs(32632))
  
germany  <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf", country = "Germany")
germany <- st_transform(germany, 32632)

ggplot()+
  geom_contour_filled(data = no2_kriging, aes(x = x, y = y, z=var1.pred))+
  geom_sf(data = germany,  fill = "transparent", color = "black")+
  geom_sf(data = points, size = 0.5, color = "red")
```

Comment: It might be easier to help if you share part of your data.

Comment: Is `tapas_kriging_sf` a `sf` object? Can you share your kriging process in a reproducible way? I.e  starting  from loading relevant libraries up to an object with a similar structure to your current `tapas_kriging_sf`? Points can be (semi)-random as long as some isobands are created, maybe use some package examples like `system.file("external/no2.csv", package = "gstat")`.  It's just that ggplot is not that relevant here and vectorizing should take place before dealing with ggplot, but it can depend on kriging process -- used libraries, used input types and resulting output types.

Comment: @margusl Hi ! I did what you ask and wrote a reproductible code which is a close image to my actual one.

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano Hi ! Just added some information so you may better understand what I did to get there.

Answer (score 3):

If you simplify the process a bit and use `stars` raster as an interpolation grid, you can later use `stars::st_contour()` on the output raster to get `sf` object with isochrone polygons. Which in turn can be used to classify points through spatial join. Defining bins is now handled in `st_contour()` call.

That extra column with matching isochrones for each point can be seen in the last code block.

```r
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(gstat)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

##Data
no2 <- read_csv(system.file("external/no2.csv", 
                            package = "gstat"), show_col_types = FALSE)
no2_sf <- st_as_sf(no2, crs = "OGC:CRS84", coords = c("station_longitude_deg", "station_latitude_deg")) 
no2_sf <- st_transform(no2_sf, 32632)

##Kriging
#Interpolation raster
no2_grid <- st_bbox(no2_sf) %>% st_as_stars(dx = 10000)
# stars object:
no2_grid 
#> stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>         Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#> values     0       0      0    0       0    0
#> dimension(s):
#>   from to  offset  delta                refsys x/y
#> x    1 60  304638  10000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N [x]
#> y    1 83 6086661 -10000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N [y]

#Variogram
no2_sample_variogram <- gstat::variogram(NO2~1, no2_sf)
no2_model_variogram <- vgm(psill = 16, "Exp", range = 200000, nugget = 1)
no2_fit_variogram <- fit.variogram(no2_sample_variogram, no2_model_variogram)

#Ordinary Kriging 
# now returns stars raster:
no2_kriging <- gstat::krige(formula   = NO2~1, 
                            locations = no2_sf, 
                            newdata   = no2_grid, 
                            model     = no2_fit_variogram)
#> [using ordinary kriging]
no2_kriging
#> stars object with 2 dimensions and 2 attributes
#> attribute(s):
#>                 Min.  1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.     Max.
#> var1.pred  2.6449424 7.281307  8.214847  8.569172  9.611575 19.09527
#> var1.var   0.2019452 8.902331 11.587504 11.155864 13.871108 16.72409
#> dimension(s):
#>   from to  offset  delta                refsys x/y
#> x    1 60  304638  10000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N [x]
#> y    1 83 6086661 -10000 WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N [y]
plot(no2_kriging)
```

[image]

```r
# contrours from raster, range is ~ 3 .. 20, using seq(0, 20, 5) for breaks
isochrones <- st_contour(no2_kriging, breaks = seq(0, 20, 5))
isochrones
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 304638.2 ymin: 5256661 xmax: 904638.2 ymax: 6086661
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N
#>   var1.pred Min Max                       geometry
#> 1     [0,5)   0   5 MULTIPOLYGON (((789638.2 60...
#> 2    [5,10)   5  10 MULTIPOLYGON (((899638.2 52...
#> 3   [10,15)  10  15 MULTIPOLYGON (((544131.7 58...
#> 4   [15,20)  15  20 MULTIPOLYGON (((316428 5671...
plot(isochrones["var1.pred"], key.pos = 1)
```

[image]

```r
## Sample points
set.seed(123)

points <- st_bbox(no2_grid) %>% st_as_sfc() %>% st_sample(100) %>% st_sf()

# spatial join to classify points, try to pick few from each isochrone
points <- st_join(points, isochrones["var1.pred"]) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 2, by = var1.pred)
points
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 319406.4 ymin: 5506681 xmax: 777621.3 ymax: 5754652
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N
#>   var1.pred                 geometry
#> 1   [10,15) POINT (477184.7 5754652)
#> 2   [10,15) POINT (576638.7 5506681)
#> 3    [5,10) POINT (777621.3 5532905)
#> 4    [5,10) POINT (550024.3 5662210)
#> 5   [15,20) POINT (319406.4 5689204)
#> 6   [15,20) POINT (371319.4 5739514)

## ggplot
germany  <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf", country = "Germany")
germany <- st_transform(germany, 32632)

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = isochrones, aes(fill =  var1.pred), alpha = .6) + 
  geom_sf(data = germany,  fill = "transparent", color = "black")+
  geom_sf(data = points, color = "red") +
  geom_sf_label(data = points, aes(label = var1.pred), nudge_x = 60000, nudge_y = -25000, alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>